# Meaning of non-anticipation assumption in panel context

Tags: difference-in-difference, causal-inference

I am moving this discussion from [this comment section](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53867/discussing-difference-in-difference-assumption-of-the-treatment-assigment/53871?noredirect=1#comment88418_53871) to a full question.

Consider a binary policy $D_{it} \in \{0,1\}$ that is not randomly assigned to some units in period $t=\tau$. We have potential outcomes in treated and untreated state $Y_{i1}(t), Y_{i0}(t)$ in each period. Non-anticipation is [commonly](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01194.pdf) defined as

$$Y_{i0}(t)=Y_{i1}(t) \quad \text{for} \quad t<T_0$$

Suppose the policy is assigned based on the observed pre-treatment outcome $Y_{i}(t-1)$ with lower values of $Y_{i}(t-1)$ increasing likelihood of treatment. Does this violate non-anticipation?

Background on our discussion: In 1Muflon1's interpretation, it does because the potential outcomes in $t-1$ are not the same for the two groups (we know that $Y_{i}(t-1)$ is lower for those who got the treatment). In my interpretation it does not because treatment is in the future and in the counterfactual world of no treatment, the potential outcomes are the same for both groups.